# Release Build Linker Failure

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just finished my project and tried building it in Release for the first time. I've had previous issues with the Windows 7 SDK and the Common7 stuff located in program files(ie they were missing and I had to install them from msdn).

The build is complaining :

```
1>LINK : fatal error C1350: error loading dll 'msobj110.dll': dll not found
1>Block.obj : fatal error LNK1000: unknown error at 00A14372; consult documentation for technical support options
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Yet I looked at :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

I have the same folder under C:\Program Files..., and IDE is almost empty; doesn't have the ms libraries.

How can I know where Visual Studio picks these dll from? I'm using VS2012.

Comment: You'd better focus on getting VS to install properly.

Comment: I have a presentation tomorrow, I will show off the debug build even if it hinders the performance a bit. Re-installing seems like a good idea, thanks.